# MVC Controller action not found (404)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm am doing some MVC work on my local machine.  I'm finding that the following url is ok:

/localhost:64147/AppName/Home

But for some reason I get a 404 if I use:

/localhost:64147/AppName/Home/Index

This is when I try to navigate to the page in Chrome.  Some pointers would be great.  This is my first post so please don't flame me :)

I'm using MVC 5.2.3 and Visual Studio 2015.

Any pointer greatly appreciated.

Comment: `404 Error` clearly says that you're trying to access the resource which doesn't exists. If I am wrong please post the screenshot of your output.

Comment: Show RouteConfig as a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue. That will help with trying to identify the problem and finding a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a '/' before the link on which you click to goto this page.

Like -

```
url = '/Home/Index';
```

/localhost:64147/Home/Index is the actual url you need.

Comment: This happens when I manually type the url into the browser.  I'm using IIS Express and have set the following as my project url: /localhost:64147/AppName

Comment: Have you tried this url - /localhost:64147/Home/Index

Comment: Only the controller name and action name is required in the url unless there is any custom routing. Can you give details on the code ?